# IntelliJ IDEA logcat navigation

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, logcat

How to configure LogCat in IntelliJ IDEA to navigate efficiently?

In eclipse everything is convenient: tag, level etc...
[image]

...but in IDEA logcat is messed up. I can't see where is message from the tag that I'm looking for. How to make IDEA LogCat more like eclipse's?

[image]

Comment: This is bothering me as well. This is why I'm using the DDMS from the SDK tools, which also provides a stacktrace (which looks exactly like the one in Eclipse) until they fix this.

Comment: I didn't know that there is such a tool in sdk, I thought that it's provided by eclipse. Thanks =)

Comment: Logcat view is changed in [IDEA 13](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I use IDEA 13, but the LogCat is still unstructured sometimes: http://i.imgur.com/y2N625V.png

Comment: @DanyloVolokh don't forget to set the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

It is Possible, you are using "DEBUG" pan, better use ANDROID to see your tags.

View > Tools Windows > Android

Looks like this : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's not possible in IntelliJ but you can apply existing filter or create new filters and switch between them easily. [This](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/new-in-intellij-idea-11-improved-filtering-in-android-logcat/) should give you a start